# How to Decode The String and Fetch data from Server in android?

Tags: android, json

I want to fetch Data From Server but String is a Encode, so i am not able to fetch Encode String. So how to convert in decode it and Fetch it?.

I am able to Successfully fetch Data From Server without Encode means Normal String.

Example,

desc="PHA+PHN0cm9uZz48YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3Lm1hcnlzY2VudGVyLm9yZy9jb250ZW50L2hlYWx0aC1jYXJlLXNlcnZpY2VzIj48c3Ryb25nPk1lZGljYWwgU2VydmljZXM8L3N0cm9uZz48L2E+OiB0byBtYWtlIGFu";

My Code is,

```
public class JSONFunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
            // InputStreamReader(is, HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
```

Comment: what your json response is:

Comment: {
response: "success",
data: [
{
s_id: "5",
ser_id: "11",
ser_title: "Services",
title: "Services",
desc: "PHN0cm9uZz48YSB"
}
]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `JSON` already arriving from the server like this ?

```
{ 
   response: "success", 
   data: [ 
       { 
          s_id: "5", 
          ser_id: "11", 
          ser_title: "Services", 
          title: "Services", 
          desc: "PHN0cm9uZz48YSB" 
       } 
   ] 
}
```

---

**If not**, could you provide us some code on how your server is serving that `JSON`?

---

**If yes**, then @Akash answer will work, but i recommend you to parse your `JSON` into a `JAVA` object, for better readability and maintenance, using a external library like [Google Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Would be something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson ();
YourJavaObject object = gson.fromJson(jsonString,  YourJavaObject.class)
```

*YourJavaObject.class*

```
public class YourJavaObject {
   public Integer s_id;
   public Integer ser_id;
   public String ser_title;
   public String desc;
   public String title; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

{ response: "success", data: [ { s_id: "5", ser_id: "11", ser_title: "Services", title: "Services", desc: "PHN0cm9uZz48YSB" } ] }

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
status = obj.getString("response");
if(status.equals("success")
{

JSONArray Data = obj.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i=0;i<Data.length();i++)
{
  String s_id=Data.getJsonObject(i).getString("s_id");
  String ser_id=Data.getJsonObject(i).getString("ser_id");
  String ser_title=Data.getJsonObject(i).getString("ser_title");
  String title=Data.getJsonObject(i).getString("title");
  String desc=Data.getJsonObject(i).getString("desc");
}

}
```